# How to send a Report Generated in JasperReports Server to client's default Printer

Tags: printing, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a new requirement that a report generated in *JR Server* to be sent to the client's default printer without viewing it. Is there any way of doing this?

I'm using *JasperReports Server 6.2* on *JBoss eap 6.2*

Comment: The problem is that you can not control client printer from browser, you would need an applet or similar..

Comment: I recently worked on using the REST API of jasper report server to generate report and get the output to the client machine. I was successful in getting it as both xml and html formats. but now my problem is to send it to the printer. When I do print it just print html tags but not the output. Is there any way where I can achieve this target ?

Comment: Export to pdf and let the client print it (you can open the print dialog automatically), but not print directly to client printer via browser (if you don't develop a browser plugin for that)